# Retrieve values In the same order of values given in IN caluse

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a query like (MS ACCESS). 
The `number values in the IN caluse is a variant`.In the given example I given only 4.somethimes its more than 30 numbers.

```
SELECT        ID
FROM          TableName
WHERE        (ID IN (16, 18, 15, 20 ))

Result : 15 ,16,18,20
```

Is there any way to  retrieve values In the `same order` of values given in `IN` caluse.
Result should like  this  `Result : 16,18,15,20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell the db engine to examine the order of values in the `IN()` list and apply that same order to the `ORDER BY`.

You could apply the same ordering by using a `Switch()` expression, but then you would have to keep `Switch()` and `In()` synchronized.

```
SELECT id
FROM YourTable
WHERE id In (16,18,15,20)
ORDER BY 
    Switch(
        id=16,1,
        id=18,2,
        id=15,3,
        id=20,4
    );
```

Comment: Does switch have any limit of numbers?

Comment: I've never pushed far enough to hit a limit before.  I could extend the query above to 14 expression/value pairs ... `Switch(id=1,14,id=2,13,id=3,12,id=4,11,id=5,10,id=6,9,id=7,8,id=8,7,id=9,6,id=10,5,id=11,4,id=12,3,id=13,2,id=14,1)` ... but any more than that threw an error about "expression too complex".

Comment: So the better solution is to split the query if more than 14 numbers come.is it?

Comment: I'm not even certain the upper limit is 14 expression/value pairs.  Perhaps the limit is based on the total number of characters instead.  Apart from that, if you can accomplish what you need with multiple smaller queries instead of one large query, that seems reasonable to me.  It depends on what fits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
FROM          TableName t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 sortorder, 16 ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 18
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 15
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 20
) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY t2.sortorder
```

Comment: @Shebin You can create a temp table containing them and join it instead. I wrote it this way because there are other possible ways to do this using a `CASE` expressions, but this will be the same problem with multiple values. So I thought it will be easier to write these values as a temp table.